# Google Maps API, wont verify if key restricted

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I just cannot get the API to verify. I have followed the tutorial. Create the project, add a billing account, enable API's, create credentials, restrict key - have used HTTP as its a website and tried .domain/* and without the . It only verifies when the key is unrestricted.

I know next to nothing about this, please can someone help me.I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add my actual full domain and then the restrictions as I had them and also add a server key with my IP address as I had Geocoding and Places API's enabled.